# query on mysql table creation composite primary key from foreign keys of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, xampp

I have the following tables

```
books(
  bkid varchar(255),
  bkname varchar(255),
  bkauth varchar(255),
  bkpub varchar(255),
  bkedn int(10)
)

members(
  memid varchar(255),
  memname varchar(255),
  memaddr varchar(255),
  memcon varchar(255),
  mememail varchar(255)
)
```

`bkid` and `memid` are primary keys.

Now I am trying to make a **composite primary key (bkid and memid)** taking them as foreign keys from the tables `books` and `members,` the syntax is giving me some errors and I am not able to create the new table.

```
create table issuebooks(
  bkid varchar(255),
  memid varchar(255),
  issuestatus varchar(255),
  references foreign key bkid(books),
  references foreign key memid(members),
  primary key (bkid,memid)
);
```

Comment: @Wouter J.Error #1064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create table statement is incorrect. This will work (tested on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61050))

```
create table issuebooks(
  bkid varchar(255) references bkid(books),
  memid varchar(255) references memid(members),
  issuestatus varchar(255),
  primary key (bkid,memid)
);
```

Advice... use integer id columns instead of VARCHAR(255) if you can... you won't regret it. And make those columns NOT NULL.